# java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at 127.0.0.1:9042

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector

I [found a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30927615/4770813) but it didn't help.

I've been working with Cassandra for a little while and now I'm trying to setup spark and spark-cassandra-connector. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA to do that (first time with IntelliJ IDEA and Scala too so, you get the picture)

My OS is Windows 10. This is what I've done:

Inside **../spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/bin**: `spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master`

Inside **../spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/bin**: `spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker -c 1 spark://192.168.0.3:7077`

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

idea {
    project {
        jdkName = '1.8'
        languageLevel = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.11', version: '2.4.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.11', version: '2.4.5'
    compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: '2.11.11'
    compile group: 'com.datastax.spark', name: 'spark-cassandra-connector_2.11', version: '2.4.0'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.guava:guava:12.0.1'
    }
}

compileScala.targetCompatibility = "1.8"
compileScala.sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
```

**SparkModule.scala**

```
package org.sentinel.spark_module

import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import com.datastax.spark.connector._

object SentinelSparkModule {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
      .setAppName("Sentinel").setMaster("spark://192.168.0.3:7077")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("keyspace", "table")
    val values = rdd.groupBy((CassandraRow) => {
      @throws[Exception]
      def call(row: Nothing) = CassandraRow.getString("column")
    }).take(10).foreach(println)    
  }
}
```

Even though the error occurs, I can still see the app running in http://localhost:8080/ until I stop the execution in the IDE.
[image]

Excerpt of the full stack dump:

> *Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to open native*
>   *connection to Cassandra at {127.0.0.1}:9042*
>
> *Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All*
>   *host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042*
>   *(com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException:*
>   *[/127.0.0.1:9042] Operation timed out))*

Finally, even though it says it timed out, I am also querying Cassandra from my web app (node.js) as I'm coding this and the queries work fine. So, I don't know why it'd be a problem on Cassandra's part but, I guess it could be.

Thanks

EDIT:

I included `compile group: 'com.datastax.cassandra', name: 'cassandra-driver-core', version: '3.0.0'` and same error. ([version compatibility table](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#version-compatibility))

EDIT:

`nodetool status` shows:

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
========================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load        Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  138.59 MiB  256          100.0%            77d808e6-5c57-494a-b6fb-7e73593dbb46  rack1
```

EDIT:

`cqlsh 127.0.0.1 9042` shows:

```
WARNING: console codepage must be set to cp65001 to support utf-8 encoding on Windows platforms.
If you experience encoding problems, change your console codepage with 'chcp 65001' before starting cqlsh.

Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.4 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
WARNING: pyreadline dependency missing.  Install to enable tab completion.
cqlsh>
```

Comment: you shouldn't include cassandra driver explicitly - i'ts inside connector

Comment: can you do `nodetool status` from your Cassandra cluster

Comment: @AlexOtt *you shouldn't include cassandra driver explicitly - i'ts inside connector*. do you mean I should remove `compile group: 'com.datastax.cassandra', name: 'cassandra-driver-core', version: '3.0.0'`? also, I included `nodetool status`'s output. thanks

Comment: yes, you need to remove this dependency - everything is in the connector

Comment: can you also try to do `cqlsh 127.0.0.1 9042` ?

Comment: @AlexOtt included `cqlsh 127.0.0.1 9042`'s output, although I have been able to use cql queries from the console all along

Comment: something is strange, I'm not sure if it's the problem of Windows, or not. Let's try via `spark-shell`: execute from spark directory: `bin\spark-shell.cmd --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.5.0`. And then inside enter: `import com.datastax.spark.connector._`, then `val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("keyspace", "table")` and then `rdd.count`

Comment: @AlexOtt I think it all went well. after `rdd.count` there was a lot of logging, and finally output `res0: Long = 6646284` which I assume is the number of rows in the table

Comment: Yes. It looks like. Then we can narrow it to something with Idea setup... I would say that it could be something with firewall or something like...

Comment: @AlexOtt well, this is really odd, the error **java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at 127.0.0.1:9042** is not showing anymore. could it be simply network congestion or cassandra misconfiguration? taking into account it was being caused by **OperationTimedOutException**? instead now I'm getting **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraPartition** even after adding *spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-2.4.3* to my runtime libs. appreciate your effort and time. thanks

Comment: You use SCC for wrong Scala version

Comment: I am using now the one in maven's repository and using the versions according to [this table](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#version-compatibility) but same error. I just posted [a question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61565049/4770813), if you could answer that one and provide more detail about the versions. please, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is Cassandra also running on `192.168.0.3`? Did you try changing `spark.cassandra.connection.host` to `192.168.0.3` instead? The reason you are seeing that error is because your Spark executor cannot connect to Cassandra at `127.0.0.1`. I don't know anything about your setup, and you might have tried this already, but it could be that the solution is as simple as that.

Comment: Cassandra is running on **127.0.0.1:9042**, at least that's the one I use in my node-cassandra module config, which I use to query cassandra from node without problems. isn't **127.0.0.1:9042** then the host and port I should use from spark as well?

Comment: Where is your Spark master running? Is it on the same machine as where your Cassandra nodes are running?

Comment: yes, I'm working localhost on the whole project so everything is in the same computer. I have 1 master (**spark://192.168.0.3:7077**) and one worker in spark, and I have cassandra on **127.0.0.1:9042**

Comment: As the other comments above show, one of the possible reasons for the error is a dependency issue. The Cassandra driver [uses Guava 16.0.1](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/f52c091de3ad001102c85c334faf18beaf937deb/project/Versions.scala#L33) so you could try using that instead. For what it is worth, you can also try upgrading the Cassandra Spark Connector to version 2.5.0 (dont use 3.0 as this is not compatible with Spark 2.4).