# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraPartition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector

I've been working with Cassandra for a little while and now I'm trying to setup spark and spark-cassandra-connector. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA to do that (first time with IntelliJ IDEA and Scala too) in Windows 10.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    flatDir {
        dirs 'runtime libs'
    }
}

idea {
    project {
        jdkName = '1.8'
        languageLevel = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.11', version: '2.4.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.11', version: '2.4.5'
    compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: '2.11.12'
    compile group: 'com.datastax.spark', name: 'spark-cassandra-connector_2.11', version: '2.5.0'
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.guava:guava:12.0.1'
    }
}

compileScala.targetCompatibility = "1.8"
compileScala.sourceCompatibility = "1.8"

jar {
    zip64 true
    archiveName = "ModuleName.jar"
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.module.ModuelName'
    }
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA'

}
```

**ModuleName.scala**

```
package org.module
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType

object SentinelSparkModule {

  case class Document(id: Int, time: TimestampType, data: String)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .master("spark://192.168.0.3:7077")
      .appName("App")
      .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
      .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
      .getOrCreate()

    //I'm trying it without [Document] since it throws 'Failed to map constructor parameter id in
    //org.module.ModuleName.Document to a column of keyspace.table'

    val documentRDD = spark.sparkContext
      .cassandraTable/*[Document]*/("keyspace", "table")
      .select()
    documentRDD.take(10).foreach(println)
    spark.stop()
 }
}
```

I have a running spark master at **spark://192.168.0.3:7077** and a worker of that master, but I haven't tried to `submit` the job as a compiled jar in the console, I'm just trying to get it to work in the IDE.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra connector jar needs to be added to the **classpath of workers**. One way to do this is to build an uber jar with all required dependencies and submit to the cluster.

Refer to: [Building a uberjar with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986244/building-a-uberjar-with-gradle)

Also, make sure you change the `scope` of dependencies in you build file from `compile` to `provided` for all jars except the cassandra connector.

Reference: https://reflectoring.io/maven-scopes-gradle-configurations/

Comment: that question asks about SBT. do I have to use SBT instead of Gradle then? and the accepted answer ditches Intellij altogether, which I'd like to avoid

Comment: @Scaramouche If you want to just run the app from IntelliJ then you should install the cassandra libs in spark worker nodes as a one time thing. Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36879404/127320